# value for select in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Is there a way to select an item based on the label containing a set of characters? I can't select by index as that will change, and the items being generated in the select have some random numbers appended at the end. I'd like the basically say if the label contains "this."

is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, example in XPath:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'this')]
```

Or CSS:

```
select:contains('This')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```
<label for="blah">
     <input name="blah" id="blah" type="checkbox" />
     Store Locator Plus
</label>
```

My target to get the checkbox:

```
//label[contains(text(),'Store Locator Plus')]//input[@type="checkbox"]
```

To check it I use the command "check", the target noted above, and a value of "On", which forces the checkbox to be marked (versus using click which will toggle it on/off).